# Derivatives near optimal points

Tags: derivatives, inequality, optimization

On page 52 of [What Sustains Social Norms and How They Evolve?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016726810300221X), Assumption 1 is as follows:

> **Assumption 1:** $d$ is continuously differentiable, $d'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x<0$ and $d'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x>0$ (it follows that $d'(0)=0$).

I don't understand the use of $\ge$ and $\le$ here. If $d'(0)=0$ implies a maximum is obtained at $x=0$, then every $x$ to the left of $0$ should have a strictly positive derivative and every $x$ to the right of $0$ should have a strictly negative derivative (i.e., $>$ and $<$ should be used).

What is the meaning behind $d'(x) \ge 0$ and $d'(x) \le 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is just about $d'$ and not $d$. Note that $d$ doesn't even appear without the derivative. So if we call $f=d'$, then it says:

The function $f$ is continuous, $f(x)$ is non-negative for negative $x$, and non-positive for positive $x$. Then by continuity $f(0)=0$.

Such a function would be for example $f(x)=-2x$, so $d(x)=-x^2 + c $. Now, you can imagine what these $d$'s look like. They are increasing for negative $x$ and decreasing for positive $x$, having a local max at $x=0$.

But also $d\equiv 0$ is such a function, so we don't need strict inequality. The non strict inequality allows the function to be constant (i.e. flat) on some (proper) intervals. In fact, with the $\leq$ and $\geq$ signs, the statement is even stronger in the sense that it covers more cases. This is because in the strict inequality case, you can still apply this statement, as non-strict inequalities are also applicable for that case.